# sns.despine limits x and y axis

Tags: python, seaborn

I've been plotting some graphs using `sns.regplot` and just for astehtic reasons I implemented `sns.despine`. However, as you can see in the image `sns.despine` limits my y and x axis. How can I set the limit to the minimum and maximun datapoint? Thanks for your answer in advance! Happy to hear your suggestions!
[image]

Also, here's the code. I'm using `sns.subplot` and a for loop to generate a bunch of figures automatically:

```
for rab, hrab, rep1, rep2 in zipped_final: 
with sns.axes_style(style='ticks'):
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,3, figsize =(18,6))
    plt.tight_layout(pad=3.0)

    sns.regplot(
        ax = axes[0],
        data = rablog_df,
        x = 'expected ratio',
        y = rab,
        ci = None,
        scatter_kws={'clip_on': False})
    axes[0].set_title('LOQ' + ' ' + f'{rab}', fontsize = 16)
    axes[0].annotate('50 amol', xy =(rablog_df['expected ratio'][6], rablog_df[rab [6]))
    plt.savefig(f"{rab} 50 amol")
     
    sns.regplot(
        ax = axes[1],
        data = rabhlog_df,
        x = 'expected concentration',
        y = hrab,
        ci = None,
        scatter_kws={'clip_on': False})
    axes[1].set_title('LOD' + ' ' + f'{rab}', fontsize = 16)
    axes[1].annotate('50 amol', xy =(rabhlog_df['expected concentration'][6], rabhlog_df[hrab][6]))
    plt.savefig(f"{rab} 50 amol")
    
    sns.regplot(
        ax = axes[2],
        data = rabreplog_df,
        x = rep1,
        y = rep2,
        ci = None,
        scatter_kws={'clip_on': False})
    axes[2].set_title(f'{rab}', fontsize = 16)
    axes[2].annotate('10 amol', xy =(rabreplog_df[rep1][8], rabreplog_df[rep2][8]))
    sns.despine(offset = 20, trim = True)
    plt.savefig(f"{rab} 50 amol")'''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `trim=True` option of `sns.despine()` sets "bounds" on the x and y-axis, coinciding with the first and last of the ticks.

Instead of using `trim=True`, you could set manual bounds to the limits of the data. Note that the effect can look strange in case some ticks are outside the data range.

Here is an example using the `iris` dataset.

Some remarks:

- `plt.tight_layout()` works better when called at the end of the code, just before saving (or calling `plt.show()`)
- the question's code calls `savefig` 3 times with the same filename; these calls can be removed, except for the last one

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')
with sns.axes_style(style='ticks'):
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(18, 6))
    sns.regplot(
        ax=axes[0],
        data=iris,
        x='sepal_length',
        y='sepal_width',
        ci=None,
        scatter_kws={'clip_on': False})
    axes[0].spines['bottom'].set_bounds(iris['sepal_length'].min(), iris['sepal_length'].max())
    axes[0].spines['left'].set_bounds(iris['sepal_width'].min(), iris['sepal_width'].max())
    sns.regplot(
        ax=axes[1],
        data=iris,
        x='sepal_length',
        y='petal_length',
        ci=None,
        scatter_kws={'clip_on': False})
    axes[1].spines['bottom'].set_bounds(iris['sepal_length'].min(), iris['sepal_length'].max())
    axes[1].spines['left'].set_bounds(iris['petal_length'].min(), iris['petal_length'].max())
    sns.regplot(
        ax=axes[2],
        data=iris,
        x='petal_width',
        y='petal_length',
        ci=None,
        scatter_kws={'clip_on': False})
    axes[2].spines['bottom'].set_bounds(iris['petal_width'].min(), iris['petal_width'].max())
    axes[2].spines['left'].set_bounds(iris['petal_length'].min(), iris['petal_length'].max())
    sns.despine(offset=20)
    plt.tight_layout(pad=3)
    plt.show()
```

[image: seaborn trimming axes to the data points]

Alternatively, you can set tight margins, without trimming. Note that the ticks are a bit different compared to the previous example:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')
with sns.axes_style(style='ticks'):
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(18, 6))
    sns.regplot(
        ax=axes[0],
        data=iris,
        x='sepal_length',
        y='sepal_width',
        ci=None,
        scatter_kws={'clip_on': False})
    axes[0].margins(x=0, y=0)
    sns.regplot(
        ax=axes[1],
        data=iris,
        x='sepal_length',
        y='petal_length',
        ci=None,
        scatter_kws={'clip_on': False})
    axes[1].margins(x=0, y=0)
    sns.regplot(
        ax=axes[2],
        data=iris,
        x='petal_width',
        y='petal_length',
        ci=None,
        scatter_kws={'clip_on': False})
    axes[2].margins(x=0, y=0)
    sns.despine(offset=20)
    plt.tight_layout(pad=3)
    plt.show()
```

[image: seaborn with tight margins]